# What is "OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h file is not found" in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My application is working on simulator.There is no any error.But when running on iPhone device I get to this error

OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h  is not found

Error location 
iphoneOS6.1->Frameworks->CoreVideo.framework->CVOpenGLESTexture.h

I did not use this framework in my application.What is CVOpenGLESTexture.h ?Why I get to this error when running on device ?

Comment: Are you linking to OpenGL?

Comment: @CodaFi I use only Map in application.Is "map" OpenGL? And there is "xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" for connected device

Comment: Well, somewhere you're linking to Core Video, and Core Video requires GL (the framework's a giant wrapper around OGL contexts).

Comment: There is no any link for video in my application.And I dont have CoreVideo framework in Build Phases->Link Library

Comment: Are you using the standard iOS map control?

Comment: I am using <MapKit/MapKit.h>

Comment: try just importing the OpenGLES framework into your project and see if it fixes it

Comment: the maps use opengl but shouldn't require any add. frameworks. weird. but see if you can add that framework and import the framework header

Comment: @Fonix I dont have OpenGLES framework in Library->Framework.

Comment: Well that might be your problem, then.  Are you sure the developer tools and frameworks installed correctly?  You may have to grab a fresh copy of Xcode.